# Mosaic different data Sentinel-2 L2A image with color difference

Tags: sentinel-2, envi, sentinel-snap

I have downloaded two L2A level sentinel-2 images at 2022-09-05 and 2022-09-07 from scihub. After subset and resampling on SANP, I used seamless mosaic in ENVI to mosaic the two scenes, and I found out between the mosaic boundary has significant color difference as attached img shown. Some part of the image seems so green that the crop parcel looks very bizarre. I intend to do a pixel based classification on the image, so the color difference is detrimental to my result, is there a explanation or good way to balance the difference? If non, I think I may need to use SAR image to do classification.
[image]

Comment: Images from different dates always had this problem after mosaicking, due to the difference in reflectance values.

Comment: @ Padmanabha Thanks for your reply. The green portion seems so off that I thought the L2A product was incorrect.

Comment: @padmanabha, how did you overcome this issue? I am doing a type of land classification as well and worried about these colour differences. If you have enough training points to encompass these colour differences, does it sort itself out?

if not, did you just do a separate classification for each tile?